# How to use Parse live queries to fetch Users data?

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am still using parse for my backend, I know how to fetch data with parse normal queries ,but i am unaware of how to use parse live queries .I have read docs but the only thing i have done is to add dependecies to my gradle file.
What I want is fetching users data with live queries any example would be very helpful. For ex

```
ParseQuery<ParseUser> userParseQuery = ParseUser.getQuery();
            userParseQuery.whereEqualTo("username", driverUsername);
            userParseQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
                @Override
                public void done(List<ParseUser> objects, ParseException e) {

                    if (e == null) {

                        if (objects.size() > 0) {

                            for (ParseObject object : objects) {
                                driverLocation = object.getParseGeoPoint("location");
                            }

                    }

                }
            });
```

where should I use .subscribe()?

Comment: Assuming you are using `https://github.com/parse-community/ParseLiveQuery-Android`, you simply construct a query like usual and subscribe to it as described in the library. There are plenty examples of how to construct a user query.

Comment: @cYrixmorten I have edited my question can u please help

Comment: Not sure I understand? On the query: https://github.com/parse-community/ParseLiveQuery-Android#creating-live-queries

Comment: ill give it a try

Comment: i have one doubt, does subscriptionHandling.handleEvents(new SubscriptionHandling.HandleEventsCallback<ParseObject>() {
    @Override
    public void onEvents(ParseQuery<ParseObject> query, SubscriptionHandling.Event event, ParseObject object) {
        // HANDLING all events
    }
}) will keep on refreshing as new data will be updated on the data base?

Comment: Yep, then you can make a switch case on the event to see what kind of event it is. But the answer is yes, as long as the subscription is alive (and I assume you have enable live queries on your parse-server).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157191/discussion-between-dhami-ji-and-cyrixmorten).

Answer (score 0):

First enable Live Query in your server.

> App Settings -> Server Settings -> Server URL and Live Query

Then add the dependencies in app level `build.gradle`

```
implementation 'com.github.parse-community.Parse-SDK-Android:parse:4.1.0'
implementation 'com.github.parse-community:ParseLiveQuery-Android:1.2.2'
```

Then in the Parse initialization, add the server url which you setup in the live query in the server.

```
    Parse.initialize(new Parse.Configuration.Builder(this)
       .applicationId(getString(R.string.back4app_app_id))
       .clientKey(getString(R.string.back4app_client_key))
       .server("Your live query url here")
       .build());
```

Then you can start live query subscription and listen to changes

```
    ParseLiveQueryClient parseLiveQueryClient = ParseLiveQueryClient.Factory.getClient();
    
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> parseQuery = new ParseQuery<>("_User"); //Classname here
    parseQuery.whereEqualTo("objectId", getUser().getObjectId()); //any filtering if needed
    
    SubscriptionHandling<ParseObject> subscriptionHandling = parseLiveQueryClient.subscribe(parseQuery);
    
    subscriptionHandling.handleSubscribe(q -> {
    subscriptionHandling.handleEvents((query, event, object) -> {
                    Log.e("TAG", "onEvents: EVENT : "+ event );
                    Log.e("TAG", "onEvents: OBJCT : "+ object ); //Data fetch on update/create/delete etc.
                });
            });
```